# How to connect postgis to django in docker

Tags: django, docker, geodjango

Hi I would like to know how to connect POSTGIS to django using Docker. I am having an error `could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory`

output

```
root@localhost:~/try-geodjango# docker-compose run web python manage.py migrate
Starting try-geodjango_db_1 ... done
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 81, in handle
    connection.prepare_database()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 25, in prepare_database
    cursor.execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 300
        }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mdillon/postgis:9.4
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM evili/geodjango
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Yeah. Upvoted the answer by @Sardorbek

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**NOTE**: There is an official image for postgis now https://hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis. Use that instead. Also in example below I am using alpine which is not recommended as python base due to issues with wheels (read more https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/)

Problem here that you are not using correct postgis image

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mdillon/postgis:10 # <- here
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db  # default postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password  # default postgres
      # all env vars bellow are redundant because they are same as default values
      # - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
      # - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      # - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
```

Here is my alpine based config for working with postgis

NOTE: all my django code is stored in `./backend` folder and I use `Pipenv`, also
this project is using https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ to set `DATABASES` via `DATABASE_URL` in my settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': env.db(default='postgis://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres')
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"


services:

    postgres:
        image: mdillon/postgis:10-alpine
        volumes:
            - ./docker/postgres/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    backend:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/backend/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        volumes:
            - ./backend:/project/backend


volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

**docker/backend/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.8

# postgresql-client is required by psql
# postgresql-dev musl-dev gcc are required by psycopg
# NOTE: there is py3-psycopg2
# libxml2-dev libxslt-dev are required by lxml
# gdal-dev geos-dev proj4-dev are required by geodjango
# libcrypto1.1 is required by gdal
# NOTE: we actually need gdal-dev not gdal
# linux-headers is required by uwsgi
# gettext-dev is required by ./manage.py makemessages

# TODO: optimize installation by using --virtual
RUN apk update && apk upgrade \
    && apk add postgresql-client \
        postgresql-dev \
        musl-dev \
        gcc \
        libxml2-dev \
        libxslt-dev \
        linux-headers \
        gettext-dev \
    && apk add --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main \
        libcrypto1.1 \
    && apk add --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
        gdal-dev \
        geos-dev \
        proj4-dev \
    && pip install pipenv

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8

COPY docker/backend/docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

WORKDIR /project/backend

COPY backend/Pipfile backend/Pipfile.lock /project/backend/

RUN pipenv install --system --ignore-pipfile --dev
```

**docker/backend/docker-entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
# NOTE: if there is no bash can cause
# standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

# https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/
set -euo pipefail

WAIT_FOR_POSTGRES=${WAIT_FOR_POSTGRES:-true}

if [[ "$WAIT_FOR_POSTGRES" = true ]]; then
    DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL:-postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres}

    # convert to connection string
    # https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING
    POSTGRES_URL=${DATABASE_URL%%\?*}
    # https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion
    POSTGRES_URL=${POSTGRES_URL/#postgis:/postgres:}

    # let postgres and other services (e.g. elasticsearch) to warm up...
    # https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2017/03/14/production-ready-dockerfile-your-python-django-app/
    until psql $POSTGRES_URL -c '\q'; do
        >&2 echo "Postgres is not available - sleeping"
        sleep 1
    done
    # >&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
fi

if [[ $# -ge 1 ]]; then
    exec "$@"
else
    echo "Applying migrations"
    python manage.py migrate --noinput -v 0
    echo "Generate translations"
    python manage.py compilemessages --locale ru -v 0
    echo "Starting server"
    exec python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
fi
```

Comment: Ok. i'm trying that and will let you know shortly.

Comment: Almost running. I got this error : `Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" ?` but the container is up and running on  `LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432 \ LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432 \
 LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"` . Searching on the internet shows me that for a compiled `postgre`, the unix socker is at "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?. So still puzzled.

Comment: @iMitwe You probably setup your `DATABASES` incorrectly, please reread carefully my example

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on ubuntu 18.04 by following the installation instructions for postgis detailed here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/

In a nutshell, run: `sudo apt install postgis`.

You may also need to execute commands detailed here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/spatialite/

I'm not fluent int docker, so translate this theory accordingly.

Comment: in alpine, stuff is different